# How do you validate that an input string only contains a set of letters?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to write a function that takes in a string of any number of characters, and validates that the string contains only a predefined set of characters (none to many of each of those four characters).

```
validRna(strand) {
    var checkStrand = strand.match(/^(CGAT)$/g)
    return checkStrand == strand
}
```

Currently what I have will only match to the first character and not the whole string. I'm trying to understand both the best method to check with, and how to build the Regex (always struggled with regular expressions).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Perhaps provide a helpful resource rather than just a condescending comment?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Casimir, Judging by the fact that at one point this post had 8+ I'm assuming I'm not the only one confused. I spent 4 hours looking into regex on this prior to requesting help. Please be rude elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, for the follow up. I tried using some n{} repetition stuff that I was seeing, but was unable to make it work for this particular case. I'll take a look at that link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex pattern such as `/^[CAGT]*$/` and the `test()` method to check each string.

`[]` will match any character within that set and `*` means 0 or more of those characters. So this essentially says from the start: `^` to the end `$` there must be 0 or more of C or A or G or Ts.

```js
console.log(/^[CAGT]*$/.test("GAFASF"));
console.log(/^[CAGT]*$/.test("CAGTGAGA"));
console.log(/^[CAGT]*$/.test("GGATCAGCTTGA"));
```

```
validRna(strand) {
    return /^[CAGT]*$/.test(strand);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the portions you created with regex! I appreciate it. The part that really had me stumped was figuring out how to have them be repeated. I tried the variation of using ^ and end of string/line limiters as well but missed the repetition part!